# Getting current and previous value

Tags: c#, linq

In the LINQ query below, I would like to add a property that gets the previous `Department` as well as the current `Department`.

The LINQ query below returns:

```
EffectiveDate EmployeeID  Department
11/4/2012     10          0000 
1/14/2013     10          9121 
2/2/2016      10          9123
```

How can I show the previous `Department` next to current `Department` like this?

```
EffectiveDate EmployeeID  Department PreviousDepartment
11/4/2012     10          0000       null
1/14/2013     10          9121       0000
2/2/2016      10          9123       9121
```

Here's the current query

```
var users = from s in userTable
            where s.EmployeeID == "10"
            group new {s} by new { s.EmployeeID, s.Department} into g
            select new 
            {
                EffectiveDate = g.Max(m => m.s.EffectiveDate), 
                EmployeeID = g.Key.EmployeeID, 
                Department = g.Key.Department
                //PreviousDepartment = ???
            };
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you do `group new {s}` instead of `group s`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to store the data in memory, and then modify it like this:

```
var users = from s in userTable
            where s.EmployeeID == "10"
            group new {s} by new { s.EmployeeID, s.Department} into g
            select new MyClass
            {
                EffectiveDate = g.Max(m => m.s.EffectiveDate), 
                EmployeeID = g.Key.EmployeeID, 
                Department = g.Key.Department
                PreviousDepartment = null
            };

var result = users.ToList();

for(int i = 1; i < result.Count; i++)
{
    result[i].PreviousDepartment = result[i-1].Department;
}
```

Please note that the code is generating new instances of `MyClass` instead of an anonymous type since anonymous type properties are read-only. Make sure that you create such class with the correct properties.

Comment: Thanks, Yacoub.  This accomplished what i needed.  Regarding your question about "group new {s}", i was using that in Linqpad because i was getting an error with "group s".

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a current and previous pair using the `Zip` method in LINQ. One downside is that it does enumerate the input twice (which may be an issue if it's coming from a database), but on the other hand it does not hold the whole of the input in memory and it's lazy (i.e you don't have to consume it all).

For example, using int values as a demo:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CurrentAndPrevious()
{
    var input = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    var output = Enumerable.Repeat(0,1)   // an initial zero value
         .Concat(input)                   // followed by the list
                                          // zipped with the list
         .Zip(input, (x, y) => new {current = y, previous = x});

    // a test that passes (using FluentAssertions syntax)
    string.Join(",", output.Select(x => $"({x.current},{x.previous})"))
       .Should().Be("(1,0),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,4)");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, Ian.  I'm getting errors when applying it using my list, so would need to spend more time looking at it.  Get an error on the .Concat extension method, even though when i run your code, i don't.

Answer (score 1):

**Most of the other answers force the `IEnumerable` to be iterated fully, in some cases twice.** It is possible to do this without any extra iteration, in other words: inline with the LINQ iteration flow.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<(T current, T previous)> WithLag<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var previous = default(T);
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        yield return (item, previous);
        previous = item;
    }
}
```

You can then use this in normal LINQ fashion (you need method syntax):

```cs
var users = userTable
            .Where(s => s.EmployeeID == "10")
            .GroupBy(s => new { s.EmployeeID, s.Department})
            .WithLag()
            .Select(gLag => new 
            {
                EffectiveDate = gLag.current.Max(m => m.s.EffectiveDate), 
                EmployeeID = gLag.current.Key.EmployeeID, 
                Department = gLag.current.Key.Department
                PreviousDepartment = gLag.previous.Key.Department
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Interactive Extensions (NuGet package Ix-Main) you could do the following:

```
var users = 
    userTable
    .Where(x => x.EmployeeID == "100")
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.EmployeeID, x.Department })
    .Select(x => new
        {
            EffectiveDate = x.Max(m => m.EffectiveDate),
            EmployeeID = x.Key.EmployeeID,
            Department = x.Key.Department
        })
    .OrderBy(x => x.EffectiveDate)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Scan(
        new
        {
            EffectiveDate = default(DateTime),
            EmployeeID = default(string),
            Department = default(string),
            PreviousDepartment = default(string)
        },
        (a, x) => new
        {
            EffectiveDate = x.EffectiveDate,
            EmployeeID = x.EmployeeID,
            Department = x.Department,
            PreviousDepartment = a.Department
        });
```

The benefit is that you stick with the declarative programming style.  The downside is that it is more verbose and possibly harder to read than operating on the data in memory.  Oh, and you may have to install a NuGet package.  For me it is less of an issue because I don't think I start any project without adding Ix-Main.

Ix-Main, never leave home without it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, Jason.  Unfortunately, can't install extensions at our company without going through alot of red tape.

Answer (score 0):

A Method Syntax for achieving it.

```
var result = userTable.Select((x, i) => { Department j = null ; if (i>0) j = userTable.ElementAt(i-1).Department;  return new { x.EffectiveDate , x.EmployeeID  , x.Department , j};});
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, Shashwat, i was receiving an error "type or namespace Department could not be found", on the first Department reference.