# How to select an item and the previous from an IEnumerable<>?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I would like to know if it is possible to select from an IEnumerable a value and the value just before.

For ex :

```
IEnumerable<string>  my_Enu
```

Which is a collection of items `("A","B","C","D","E")` for ex.

I would like to create a second IEnumerable :

```
IEnumerable<string> test_Enu = my_Enu.Where(item => item =="C")
```

And I would like to add too the previous item which is `"B"`.

Could you please tell me if there is a way to do it?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# linq getting current and previous value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711373/c-sharp-linq-getting-current-and-previous-value) a [Get current and previous Item with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768298/get-current-and-previous-item-with-linq)

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759849/get-previous-and-next-item-in-a-ienumerable-using-linq

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use simple LinkedList.

```
IEnumerable<string> collection = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
var linkedList = new LinkedList<string>(collection);
var element = linkedList.Find("C");
var result = new[] { element, element.Previous };
```

And of course you would need to add null-checks

Comment: Adding to this another approach: var test_Enu = my_Enu
                .TakeWhile(x => x != "C")
                .TakeLast(1)
                .Append("C"); will also give you the two elements.